# A cup of a tea's time

Tags: phrases, idioms

is it understandable to ask "a cup of tea's time" to one of your colleagues? meaning, I won't bother you longer than 5-10 minutes. That's a common way to approach it in my country (Italy), though we replace "tea" with "coffee" :-)
Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you going to serve them a cup of tea? Certainly if you said "do you have time for a cup of tea" and I didn't get any tea, I'd be annoyed.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  It’s a reasonable question.  There are many expressions from other languages that hover on the edges of common English usage.

Comment: I didn't downvote but it doesn't show any research effort - it would be simple to search Google or Google Books and see what you found in English langauge texts.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard this expression used in English, whether referring to coffee or tea. We would just say 'a few minutes'.

Comment: I agree entirely with this answer.  But to answer the question asked - yes, the phrase *a cup of tea's time* is entirely comprehensible, and charmingly quirky (or quirkily charming) to the native ear which has never heard it before.

Answer (score 0):

I love this colloquialism, and yes I understood it naturally. Admittedly I do drink lots of tea, and maybe that affected my answer, but yes I love it and intend to use it as frequently as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the idiom but I don't believe that it would be immediately understandable in the British context. Much more common would be the request

> "Can I have five minutes of your time please?"

This would not trigger the setting of a timer on the part of the other person but, if they were very time-constrained or had an imminent meeting they would say

> "Yes, but it will have to be five minutes."

If they were less time-constrained they would expect the meeting to extend somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

No, "Can I have a cup of tea's time?" doesn't communicate well in that sense. And as [Stuart F](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/596462/a-cup-of-a-teas-time#comment1500598_596462) commented, "Do you have time for a cup of tea?" *is* offering tea, not merely using the duration of (hypothetical) consumption as a unit of time.

The Aussie colloquial "[two shakes](https://grammarist.com/idiom/in-two-shakes-of-a-lambs-tail/#:%7E:text=In%20two%20shakes%20of%20a%20lamb%E2%80%99s%20tail%20describes,as%20dead%20lambs%20do%20not%20shake%20their%20tails.)" gets closer to your intent:

- Could I have a word? It won't be two shakes (of a lamb's tail).

You can use other activities if you explicitly include a time reference:

- [It'll be *quicker* than you can **say** Jack Robinson](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/quicker+than+you+can+say+Jack+Robinson).

Normally, though, English is a lot more straightforward when it comes to time:

- Do you have a minute?

Although, depending on who's asking, you might want to take that minute with a pinch of salt.

Answer (score -4):

words and phrases can change when they are transferred from the source language to the target language. so, I guess unless the meaning is not changed and your colleague is also Italian; then it would be possible to replace the word "tea" with "coffee".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer isn't clear. You're saying it's not comprehensible?